# How to custom tabcontrol like preference of Dropbox in Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to custom tabcontrol in windows form like preference of Dropbox.
[image]

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use winforms for this, have a look at WPF, you should be able to achieve this through creating your own style.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx

http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html

Comment: Why he "shouldn't"? If he wants or needs winforms implementation why force him to use WPF? Switching to WPF just to achieve one fancy GUI effect is pure nonsense.

Comment: Since its purely a GUI issue it makes sense to use WPF as it will allow him to achieve this exact result in a much neater and more efficient way, but fair point if he specifically requires a winforms solution then he should follow your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TabControl.ImageList` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.imagelist.aspx). You will be able to add images to each tab. But I'm not sure if you will be able to achieve exactly the same result as your screenshot shows. If not, and the result is not acceptable, you can use panels and picture boxes - you can hide/show each panel when user clicks appropriate picture box.

[Edit] You could also draw tabs on your own but it would require a lot of additional work.